# Heroku and RoR server on Ubuntu 64bit 11.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ubuntu-11.04

So I want to deploy my app to Heroku, registered the account and did other necessary things. But I ran on a problem running command `heroku keys:add`. Here's the errors I get:

```
ruby@Rubuntu:~/rails_projects/first_app$ heroku keys:add
/home/ruby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)
from /home/ruby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/ruby/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-2.1.4/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ruby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/ruby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/ruby/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-2.1.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:17:in `block in load'
from /home/ruby/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-2.1.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:16:in `each'
from /home/ruby/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-2.1.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:16:in `load'
from /home/ruby/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-2.1.4/bin/heroku:13:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ruby/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
from /home/ruby/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

Help me out please!

PS! I am learning RoR using this book:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec:install_rubygems

Comment: "/home/ruby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)"

Something's missing!

Comment: Well, I understand it, I'm hoping that this is common problem for newbies at RoR and maybe someone know the quick fix for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Solution here](http://blog.project-sierra.de/archives/1534)

Comment: Ty a lot! Guess I need to practice more my Google skills:)

Comment: Indeed. :D Googling for something like **`require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)** helps more than the whole line, since it's looking for less keywords & the possibility of variations is lessened. or that's what I thought all this time.

Comment: :) PS! If that's you on the picture, you look great for a developer :) Also, since you are an Ruby evangelist, can you recommend some nice tutorials/books for beginners? As I mentioned before, I am learning using this book at the moment: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: On Cygwin you need to install the readline package (vs libreadline-dev), then follow the solution above.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a fairly common problem on Ubuntu.  From [this](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=14452) post on another forum:

> On my system Ubuntu (Hardy 8.04) I
>   required libncurses5-dev and
>   libreadline5-dev (installed with
>   apt-get install . Re-run
>   "ruby extconv.rb" and it will show you
>   whether anything else is missing, or
>   create a makefile.  Once you have your
>   makefile, run make, then make install.

Answer (score 2):

Using rvm solved all the problems.

Install RVM with ruby:
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

Additionally with rails:

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails

$ gem install heroku

$heroku login
```